# Javascript with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web

I am new with javascript and want to learn how to use javascript in ASP.NET MVC. Until now I use bootstrap but I realize javascript is neccessary for web programming. So what do you think about where can I start with it ? Do you recommend a resource or a study plan ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use mozilla developer network for javascript it contains some best material to improve and optimize your javascript skills go to this url
https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: Do you think I learn javascript syntax first ? I know C# and Java syntax and watch a few tutorials for javascript but they are so beginner level but that is not I am looking for. I am looking how to use js in mvc view and what exactly happens in there.

Comment: yes, start from the basics ,And java and javascript are two different things don't compare them , basically if your javascript basics are not clear then u wont be able to solve many logical problems basics like what are the meaning of undefiend and NaN in Javascript , differnce between == and === etc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics try this link , this link have everything what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

These are good resource for education purposes:

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started

https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html

Comment: I know asp.net mvc logic already. What i am looking for is how to use it with js. And I saw in most project there is jquery. Do you think start directly jquery. Because when I watch javascript tutorials, it makes me feel that I know already these.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend starting from JS itself for example here: https://www.codeschool.com/learn/javascript

Then you shoud try to "connect" it with other technologies when you will feel confident.

Comment: Thank you sir. It looks like useful. I already started my roadtrip